# Validating user's input before creating graph using TChart

Tags: delphi

The user enters coefficients into input boxes on a form, called `GetFunction`. Upon clicking an <kbd>OK</kbd> button on said form, the input is validated using `TryStrToFloat. If all the input boxes are valid,`CreateGraph`is called. As soon as an invalid input box is found,`CreateGraph` should not be called and the user should be able to fix their error.

```
procedure TfrmGetFunction.btnAddFunctionClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i : integer; // Loop counter.
  begin
    for i := 1 to 7 do
      begin
        CoefficientEdit[i].CoValid := CheckCoefficientBoxesValidInput(CoefficientEdit[i].CoEditBox);
        if not CoefficientEdit[i].CoValid then // If any input box is invalid.
          Exit;
      end;
    frmGraphingMode.CreateGraph; // Finally if all input boxes valid.
    frmGetFunction.Visible := false;
    frmGraphingMode.Visible := true;
  end;
```

Any improvements that I could make? Perhaps removing the *Exit* may not be a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

Besides deciding if a coefficient is valid or not the function `CheckCoefficientBoxesValidInput` can also say **what is wrong** and suggest **how** the user can **fix it**.

In order to communicate such information up to the caller and up to the user interface you can use throwing an **exception**.

Main success scenario would mean no `if`s, just sequence of statements.

Exceptional flow would be encoded in `try/except` blocks, either in this function or somewhere upwards or in the final `Application.OnException` handler.

Whether the code would be easier to maintain or not is only opinion-based matter of taste and your established coding conventions.

The main improvement would be that the end-user would know what happened and what to do next.

See also:

- normative [MSDN: Windows → Dev Center - Desktop → Design → Guidelines → Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742471.aspx)
- informative [MSDN: Documentation → Framework Design Guidelines → Design Guidelines for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014(v=vs.110).aspx)